# How to pass styles in typescript interface using tailwindcss and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have the types.ts file which contains my interface CustomCardProps with the values  and I passed it to the CUstomCard ,also I have the home.tsx file where I am rendering the card .More also I have a contant folder with index.ts file where I place the values of the interface values in an array of object so I can render my CustomCard dynamically in the home.tsx file by mapping through it .The problem is that the background styles and border styles does not render but all other values like tittle and value renders on the view

I have tried debugging but still no headway [[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10jQ5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqhD1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhGQW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEirS.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended in the documentation to use full classnames and not half constant-half dynamic names.

So you could try changing your background styles to the full classnames.

For example.

```js
const customStyle = {borderColor: 'border-green-600'}
```

And then use the full classnames in your code.

```js
<div className={`text-xl ${customStyle.borderColor}`}>Test</div>
```

Please refer to the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: still having the same issue . please I need assistance

Comment: Can you please inspect the respective element and check if the classnames are applied to the respective div? Please attach the screenshot of the inspect element browser tool.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was to define the styles in my css file then include the style name in the constant file ,so that way tailwind knows the styles configuration before time to enable it compile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).